# Talend job to select record from SqlServer db , execute queries and then update each record one by one

Tags: sql-server, etl, talend

i have the following table on SqlServer database

TABLE_FOR_TOS

| Query | state | DataInsert | Error | Dataexecution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| select * from Users | 0 | 2021:06:13 00:00:00 | null | null |
| select * from Clients | 0 | 2021:06:13 00:00:00 | null | null |
| select * from Business | 0 | 2021:06:13 00:00:00 | null | null |

I need to create a Talend job in TOS to :

1. select all the records from TABLE_FOR_TOS
2. fetch the record one by one to execute the query inserted in the "query" field
3. update each record changing "state" field from "0" to "1" and DateExecution from "null" to "getdate()"

I'm able to connect to SqlServer and execute the query using TDbInput component.

In order to iterate all the records one by one I'm trying to user TFlowToIterate component..

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the executed queries ? Are they all "select" queries ? The difficulty will be with managing schemas (which will be different between all your queries...) If you have a licensed product, you have "Dynamic" data type which will help you manage this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I know the problem of the dynamic schema in the TOS free.